# Problems Connecting Dell Display to Lenovo P50 Running Fedora 24

Tags: fedora, display, displayport

I currently have a Lenovo P50 running Fedora 24 and I can't seem to connect my external Dell E2715H monitor to it. I am connecting it via DP-Mini DP and as when I do so the monitor immediately results with "Entering Power Save Mode".

When I also select my display settings it isn't picking up the monitor it seems, and when I try to identify all monitors it doesn't pick it up. Have already tried going into the BIOS and running it with the "discrete" display settings, but still no luck. Also ran `xrandr` and this is the output:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3840 x 2160, maximum 8192 x 8192 eDP-1
 connected 3840x2160+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 346mm x 194mm 3840x2160 60.00*+ 2048x1536 60.00 
1920x1440 60.00 
1856x1392 60.01 
1792x1344 60.01 
1600x1200 60.00 
1400x1050 59.98 
1280x1024 60.02 
1280x960 60.00 
1024x768 60.04 60.00 
960x720 60.00 
928x696 60.05 
896x672 60.01 
800x600 60.00 60.32 56.25 
700x525 59.98 
640x512 60.02 
640x480 60.00 59.94 
512x384 60.00 
400x300 60.32 56.34 
320x240 60.05
```

Would love to see if anyone has some possible answers/solutions. Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Aren't DP Mini DP those Apple specific cables?  Why are you sing those?

Comment: Not to my knowledge. They're compatible with NVIDIA GPUs

Comment: Hmm... neither apple or NVIDIA are famous for being linux friendly.  `xrandr` finds something, therefore the kernel knows about the screen.  But you may as well suffer from problems with the driver of the card or from the control of the DP mini bus.